# Normal Posts and Custom Posts with Date Query

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I have a custom post type with a date query and these posts only shows on the post archive list when I create a normal non custom post and save this normal post then both the custom post and normal post show up. From what I understand (little) I think the issue is related to the post meta data right? And the post meta data not being saved. How do I make the post meta data save when custom post type is saved? And also why does the custom post show up after I save a normal post? Please answer that too so I understand the logic.

I tried adding this code and this code only seems to work if there are currently other posts with the same date, (year and month). If it is a new date that has no other posts then the archive does not show the post yet.

```
function save_my_metadata($ID = false, $post = false){
 global $ah,$eros;
 if($post->post_type != $eros)
  return;
 update_post_meta($ID,'my_metadata',$_POST['my_metadata']);
}
add_action('save_post','save_my_metadata');
add_action('post_updated','save_my_metadata');
```